# how to use the parent option in flutter in cloudfirestore?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to know what does the parent option return inside in streambuilder since it is not mentioned in the documentation:

```
Firestore.instance
         .collection('Doctors')
         .Parent()
         .snapshots(),
```

does this return the document's data that is containing this subcollection? Or does it return something different??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `parent` method](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/parent.html):

> For subcollections, parent returns the containing `DocumentReference`.
>
> For root collections, `null` is returned.

The way you've now written it `Doctors` is a top-level collection. For such a collection calling `parent()` returns `null`.